# Cannot update UI outside of widget using flutter Bloc pattern

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, stream-builder

I am trying out Bloc in flutter. It seems to work fine when calling a block function in a stateful widget for example:

```
 RaisedButton(
 onPressed: () => _nextStep(),
 child: Text("Next"))
```

This would call the _nextStep() function and update the UI.
The nextStep function:

```
  _nextStep() async {
_bloc.StepEventSink.add(NextStep());
}
```

and I scafold the widget with StreamBuider and that works. But if i call _nextStep() outside of the class, the data updates but the UI don't. Example:

```
class FormWizard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _FormWizardState createState() => _FormWizardState();
  next() {
_FormWizardState()._nextStep();
  }
 }
```

How can I update the UI outside of the widget?

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by using Provider State management. I declared a SteppBloc class and and assign the current step to 0. Then use **notifyListeners** to update the value on widgets that uses it.

StepBloc class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StepperBloc extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _current = 0;
  int get currentStep => _current;

  set currentStep(int val) {
    _current = val;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  increment() {
    _current++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  decrement() {
    _current--;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Then I wrap the main Widget with **ChangeNotifierProvider** of StepperBloc

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<StepperBloc>.value(value: StepperBloc())
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: theme(),
        home: loading(),
        //initialRoute: SplashScreen.routeName,
        routes: routes,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```